# Screen Reader not announcing correct aria-expanded state after button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on a page with a button that opens an Angular Material mat-sidenav and trying to make it accessible. I have aria-expanded="false" set on the button and that is working correctly. When the button is clicked and the sidenav opens, aria-expanded toggles to true. Screen reader announces all this correctly. When the 'close' button is clicked inside the sidenav, aria-expanded is set back to false but the screen reader announces the button as expanded instead of collapsed.

In my research, I came across the advice to add 'hidden' to the sidenav when it's not open and that would make sure it is hidden/closed to screen readers so I have added that as well but the button with aria-expanded="false" is still being announced as 'expanded' after the sidenav is closed.

My question is, is there anything additional I may need to add to get the screen reader to make the correct announcement? Or is there anything different I should try? This is an Angular 13 app.

Here is my button code:

```
<button (click)="openCart()" [attr.aria-expanded]="ariaExpanded">
```

and Sidenav:

```
<mat-sidenav #cartFlyout
             mode="'over'"
             class=""
             position="end"
             [fixedInViewport]="true"
             [opened]="showCart"
             [ngClass]="status ? 'open' : 'hidden'">
```

I can verify in Chrome inspector that the aria state is toggling correctly and that 'hidden' is being added to the sidenav when closed. Screen reader is NVDA and I have tested in both Chrome and Firefox with the same results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I use `aria-expanded` all the time and it works great toggling the value.  It works with all screen readers and all browsers so there must be something else going on.  Do you have an example we can try?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I was hoping someone else had run into this same issue or something similar and there was just some small thing I was missing. Thank you for taking a look. I've been having a hard time with getting Angular Material components to pass accessibility so I'm not sure if this is another one of those issues with the sidenav. Looking at code alone, seems like it should be working for the screen reader (imo)

Comment: Can you post what the generated code looks like?  That is, when everything is resolved to basic HTML elements instead of mat-this or mat-that?

Comment: it looks like I'm not allowed to paste images in posts yet but here's what the button code looks like before it's been clicked: <button aria-expanded="false">  Once it's been clicked, this changes to <button aria-expanded="true"> (which is correct, button click opens the sidenav slideout). Clicking the 'close' button that closes the slideout, this changes the button back to <button aria-expanded="false"> but the screen reader still announces the state as expanded.  Hope this helps!